# Update UISlider value Video Player

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, vimeo-api

I am playing a video using the VIMVideoPlayer and am trying to update the value of UISlider so that it reflects the current time of the player. This however does not update the value at all.

The minimum value of the UISlider is 0, maximum value is 1 and the current value is 0.

The delegate methods are:

```
-(void) videoPlayerView:(VIMVideoPlayerView *)videoPlayerView didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

}

-(void) videoPlayerViewDidReachEnd:(VIMVideoPlayerView *)videoPlayerView {
    [self.playerSlider setValue:0.0 animated:YES];
}

-(void) videoPlayerViewIsReadyToPlayVideo:(VIMVideoPlayerView *)videoPlayerView {

}
- (void)videoPlayerView:(VIMVideoPlayerView *)videoPlayerView timeDidChange:(CMTime)cmTime {

    float time = CMTimeGetSeconds(videoPlayerView.player.player.currentTime);
    float dur = CMTimeGetSeconds(videoPlayerView.player.player.currentItem.duration);
    float progress = time/dur;
    NSLog(@"here : %f", progress);
    if (progress > 0.0) {
        [self.playerSlider setValue:progress animated:YES];
    }

}

- (void)videoPlayerView:(VIMVideoPlayerView *)videoPlayerView loadedTimeRangeDidChange:(float)duration {

}
```

Comment: Do you see the NSLog being printed?

Comment: Yes. All the way from 0.0000 to 1.0000

Comment: That's interesting. Maybe the outlet is not well connected OR the delegate is not executed on the main thread

Comment: Did you connect it with nib file?

Comment: Outlet is connected. Delegate is executed. How do I check to see which thread the delegate is executed on ?

Comment: `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(myMethod:) withObject:anObj waitUntilDone:YES]` This will ensure it is running on main thread.